# Docker exec /bin/sh: exec format error on Arm64

Tags: docker, arm64

My Dockerfile works on x86 machine, but fails on the machine with `arm64` architecture; specifically on `a1.2xlarge` (an `aws EC2-instance`).

Error on running `docker compose up -d`

```
#0 0.462 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update]: exit code: 1
```

Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby27
ENV HOME /root
RUN apt-get update
```

docker -v

```
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
```

uname -a

```
Linux Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 9 13:06:11 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

lsb_release -a

```
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
```

Comment: That seems expected, since the processor architectures are different.  Can you provision an x86-based EC2 instance instead?

Comment: I am building a docker image here from scratch. So how is the architecture different? and its throwing an error on `RUN apt-get update`; which should run on any architecture.
Also, I am working with an AWS reserved instance and its not possible to move away from a1.2xlarge.

Comment: You're not building the image from scratch, but you're building your image based on another image, which is only supported on `linux/amd64`. Therefore, your processor architecture is different as stated by @DavidMaze. If you have access to the Dockerfile of the base image, you can include the steps in your file or rebuild it locally for your architecture, as well.

Comment: Related https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker/issues/286

Answer (score 22):

You might need to either user `docker buildx` or install [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org) or possibly both.

> QEMU is a free and open-source hypervisor. It emulates the machine’s processor through dynamic binary translation and provides a set of different hardware and device models for the machine, enabling it to run a variety of guest operating systems.

There are various methods to setting up QEMU, for example when running in a GitHub pipelines you can use the GitHub action [setup-qemu-action](https://github.com/docker/setup-qemu-action)

Assuming that you are on an ubuntu based system, first check what platforms your docker driver supports.

```
docker buildx ls
NAME/NODE DRIVER/ENDPOINT STATUS  PLATFORMS
default * docker                  
 default default         running linux/amd64, linux/386
```

now install qemu.

```
sudo apt-get install -y qemu qemu-user-static

docker buildx ls
NAME/NODE    DRIVER/ENDPOINT             STATUS  PLATFORMS
default      docker                              
  default    default                     running linux/amd64, linux/386, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

Now we have added support for arm64 architecture.

Comment: `apt install qemu-user-static` is all you need, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I would upvote this 10 times if I could. What a proper explanation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

[phusion/passenger-ruby27](https://hub.docker.com/r/phusion/passenger-ruby27) repository separates the arm64-based images via tags (as of Nov-2022).

I.e. [2.3.1](https://hub.docker.com/layers/phusion/passenger-ruby27/2.3.1/images/sha256-d751eb573ed671ec665a9bf2fd2c9f186c7ad4fafdf419cef7cca3954208fc62?context=explore) and [2.3.1-arm64](https://hub.docker.com/layers/phusion/passenger-ruby27/2.3.1-arm64/images/sha256-57631a0cacc8d402c80e9c1cc2cbc767c733b74a23c48c305eb02cc4692df4bd?context=explore)

Assuming that you want to build an **arm64** image on your **arm64** instance, a simple way to resolve this is to pass the tag as a build argument.

*Dockerfile:*

```bash
ARG BASE_TAG
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby27:$BASE_TAG
ENV HOME /root
RUN apt-get update
```

*Build examples:*

```bash
# on arm
$ docker build --build-arg BASE_TAG=2.3.1-arm64 .

# on amd
$ docker build --build-arg BASE_TAG=2.3.1 .
```