# Docker : exec /usr/bin/sh: exec format error V2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, gitlab-ci-runner

First of all, I have already read this post(and many others)
[Docker exec /bin/sh: exec format error on Arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73253352/docker-exec-bin-sh-exec-format-error-on-arm64), which is exactly the error I have, but the scenario is different.

When I do `docker image inspect my-image`, I see:

```
"Architecture": "arm64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 1131886345,
        "VirtualSize": 1131886345,...
```

Here is what I'm doing. I'm building an image in an arm64/v8 instance in AWS and uploading to Gitlab Container Registry, then this image is downloaded in another arm64/v8 instance in AWS.

I have added --platform linux/arm64/v8 in so many places, it is just crazy:

in my Dockerfile I have:

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64/v8 node:14.17.4 as builder
```

and

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64/v8 keymetrics/pm2:14-jessie
```

in my gitlab-ci.yml I have for build stage (only putting docker command info):

```
- docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64/v8 -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
```

and for deploy stage: (only putting the docker command info)

```
- docker run --platform linux/arm64/v8 -e ENV=prod -d -p 3000:3000 $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
```

Which ends up running:

```
docker run --platform linux/arm64/v8 -e ENV=prod -d -p 3000:3000 $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
```

When I go and do `docker ps -a` , container has exited, and when I do `docker logs containerid`, I get:

`exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error`.

What am I doing wrong? What do I have to do?

**EDIT**

I read more about this entry file, and I'm using in my docker file

```
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "pm2 start /path/to/ecosystem.config.js --env ${ENV}" ]
```

and this is my file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'service',
            script: 'dist/main.js',
            env: {
                "NODE_ENV": "dev",
            },
            env_prod: {
                "NODE_ENV": "prod"
            },
            env_docker: {
                "NODE_ENV": "docker"
            },
            env_qa: {
                "NODE_ENV": "qa",
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Can you post the first line of `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` ?

Comment: There is no such file... maybe that's the error, but why isn't it being created? Need my complete dockerfile?

Comment: Probably, yeah. Also note that ENTRYPOINT and CMD can be different, and ENTRYPOINT is used to invoke CMD.